# mic controlling all sound | can't use audio without mic on (feedback)

Tags: windows-xp, audio, microphone

Internal mic on thinkpad x201 (XP) has screeching feedback.

When the mic is turned mute (no way to totally disable), the result:  nothing at all can be heard even though other features are not muted.

There is no separate setting for recording.  Conexant controller is in- & out-audio.

How do I hear sound, stop the feedback & mute the mic all at once.

This problem just started today, after my cat walked across the keyboard.

Comment: Post screenshots of your sound-volume settings (`sndvol32`); make sure to post shots of both the *Playback* and *Recording* sections (*Options*->*Properties*). It’s not clear exactly which parts you did, but turn microphone-boost off and set its record-level down and mute the mic’s playback setting.     *> This problem just started today, after my cat walked across the keyboard.*   Maybe your cat emitted a static-electrical charge that shorted the mic/audio-card.